# C# DLLImport convert "const char*" to string

Tags: c#, marshalling, dllimport

I need to implement this DLLImport in C#

```
const char* PegaSolicitacao(const char* CNPJ,
                            const char* CPF,
                            const char* CRM,
                            const char* UF_CRM,
                            const char* DT_EMISSAO );
```

The Dll could be found at this link
https://farmaciapopular-portal-homologacao.saude.gov.br/farmaciapopular-portal/gbas/GBASMSB_2-Client.rar

Inside the .RAR \GBASMSB_2-Client\Ofd SDK 0.2 Windows.zip **-> gbasmsb_library.dll**

The only way that i got a return was with this code:

```
        [DllImport(@"gbasmsb_library.dll")]
    public static extern char PegaSolicitacao(string CNPJ,
                                              string CPF,
                                              string CRM,
                                              string UF_CRM,
                                              string DT_Emissao);
```

---

```
            var Teste = PegaSolicitacao("31617905000139",
                                    "99999999484",
                                    "30828",
                                    "SP",
                                    DateTime.Today.ToString("d"));
```

But the return is suposed to be a string not a char.
When I tried return a string in the DLLImport the system breaks, if I try to return a char[] I got a exception telling me about Marshaling.

Im, new at C# and never worked with MarshalAs, but looking at the Forum I tried some option like:

```
                [DllImport(@"gbasmsb_library.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public static extern char[] PegaSolicitacao([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]char[] CNPJ,
                                                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]char[] CPF,
                                                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]char[] CRM,
                                                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]char[] UF_CRM,
                                                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]char[] DT_Emissao);
```

and some other variants too, but I cant find the right option.

Comment: How is that returned `const char*` allocated?

Comment: I dont have access to the source code of the DLL, its a Third party DLL made by the Brazilian Government

Comment: Is there any documentation with it? A `const char*` is just a pointer. When it's a parameter, the marshaller can handle it, but as a return value, it needs to know what to do with that memory, otherwise it'll leak.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel just took a look at your profile, and saw that you use Java too.

In the "documentation" there is a similar function with a Java wrapper https://farmaciapopular-portal-homologacao.saude.gov.br/farmaciapopular-portal/gbas/GAS_GBAS_MS_Guia_Programador_Web_v2.1_20110118.pdf


`public java.lang.String PegaSolicitacao( java.lang.String CNPJ,
java.lang.String CPF,
java.lang.String CRM,
java.lang.String UF_CRM,
java.lang.String DT_EMISSAO )
throws java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't help. Doesn't show how the memory for that string is allocated and, more importantly, how it needs to be freed.

Comment: That is my main problem. 
I dont even know what it can be.

Comment: Return `IntPtr` and marshal to string  `Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(...)`

Comment: @sidprasher That will handle the marshalling part, but maybe it'll also cause a memory leak because the pointer might need to be freed, but to free you need to know how it was allocated.

Comment: You need to read the documentation for the DLL. You need to find out how the returned string was allocated.

Comment: @sidprasher How should I use it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan As I told above, the only documentation that I have is this. The DLL was made by the Government and I dont the source of the DLL

Comment: So ask the government. Or guess.

Answer (score 3):

**Using the DLL**

I've used DLL Export Viewer to see the exported functions. A quick google search resulted in these C export definitions:

```c
const char* IdentificaEstacao();
const char* PegaSolicitacao( const char* CNPJ, const char* CPF, const char* CRM, const char* UF_CRM, const char* DT_EMISSAO );
const char* PegaConfirmacao( const char* CNPJ, const char* NU_AUTORIZACAO, const char* NU_CUPOM_FISCAL );
```

Because of its simplicity, I decided to start with `IdentificaEstacao` which should return an identifier that identifies the station.

I've tried all kind of return `MarshalAs`, `CharSet` and `CallingConvention` values, but couldn't get it working with an import that returns a `string` type. So let's change the return type to `IntPtr` instead:

```cs
[DllImport("gbasmsb_library.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr IdentificaEstacao();
```

Now, when calling that function, you'll get back an `IntPtr` that points to a memory address. When checking the content of that memory location (*Debug > Windows > Memory > Memory1* while pausing on a breakpoint), you can see a single-byte, null-terminated string (looks like Base64 data).

I tried freeing it with one of the `Marshal.Free...` methods, but that didn't work. I've called the same method several times and each time we're getting back the same memory address in the `IntPtr` which makes me guess that they're using a global allocated string that should not be freed by the caller (that might also be the reason why the `string` return type doesn't work).

With the code below, we're able to get the station identifier:

```cs
var ptr = IdentificaEstacao();
var stationIdentifier = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
```

Let's change the signature of the other import in the same way:

```cs
[DllImport("gbasmsb_library.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr PegaSolicitacao(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string CNPJ,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string CPF,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string CRM,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string UF_CRM,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string DT_Emissao);
```

And make this test call:

```cs
var ptr = PegaSolicitacao("31617905000139",
                           "99999999484",
                           "30828",
                           "SP",
                           DateTime.Today.ToString("d"));
```

This again returns a pointer to a static string (calling it multiple times returns the same memory address), so you can just get the result by calling `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);` again.

As an additional test, I've ran this in a tight loop and there seems to be no memory leak, so this should be a pretty safe way of calling the imported function(s).

Note that I have changed the `CallingConvention` from `StdCall` to `Cdecl` so we can use `string` as input parameters without getting the *unbalanced stack* exception.

**Using the EXE**

I've also noticed that the archive contains an executable `gbasmsb_gbas.exe` which can perform the same functions.

`gbasmsb_gbas.exe --i` gives you the station identifier, while `gbasmsb_gbas.exe --solicitacao 99999999484 31617905000139 30828 SP 12/03/2019` returns the request info.

Calling the EXE and parsing the output is also a possible integration path that is less prone to breaking changes for future updates of that external library.

Comment: Thanks, ill try it and report back

Comment: There is a difference between the DLL result and the EXE result.
Maybe its a Encoding issue.